# ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package biblatex. while there is no duplicate of code

Tags: biblatex

I am pretty new to LaTeX and I try to write a report where I could cite papers with a author-year style. Right now everything works fine while citing papers, but I only get the plain `[index]` citation. I have looked through a lot of different options, and none work (from `natbib` package, to `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`, etc etc) so I try with `\usepackage[..., style=authoryear]{biblatex}` but I get the error:

> ```
> ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package biblatex.
> ```

However, I don't see where it could come from? There is no duplicate commands of `\usepackage{biblatex}` or something similar... Here is a short version of my document:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{report}
% ----------- preamble -----------------
\usepackage[BScProject, lablogo]{EPFLreport}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=alphabetic,
    citestyle=authoryear
  ]{biblatex}

% ----------- Text -----------
%
% Blah blah blah
%
% ----------------------------

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: If the document as posted already produces the option clash error chances are that `EPFLreport` already loads `biblatex` with different options. I don't know `EPFLreport` and can't find an official source for it. Can you give us a link where we an obtain `EPFLreport.sty`?

Comment: Note that `style=alphabetic, citestyle=authoryear` is a weird combination of options/styles anyway. It will give you author-year citations (like Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998) in the text, but you will have alphabetic labels (like SR98) in the bibliography. Unless you put in extra work the alphabetic labels will not appear in the document and will only serve to confuse your readers. Either choose `style=alphabetic` or `style=authoryear,`.

Comment: Oh you are right, I didn't think about `EPFLreport.sty`, where it indeed already loads `biblatex` ! It were given to me by my university. I will change the cite style inside of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this simple document already reproduces the option clash, chances are `EPFLreport` already loads `biblatex`. The only `EPFLreport.sty` that I could find on the net is https://github.com/HexHive/thesis_template/blob/master/EPFLreport.sty and indeed it loads `biblatex`.

That `EPFLreport.sty` has no option to stop it from loading `biblatex` or a way to influence the loading options, so your only straightforward choices are

1. Don't load `EPFLreport.sty`.
2. Modify a ***renamed* copy** of `EPFLreport.sty` to load `biblatex` with the desired options and load that.

---

I should add that

```
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=alphabetic,
    citestyle=authoryear
  ]{biblatex}
```

is a bit of a weird combination as it will give you author-year citations (like *Sigfrdisson and Ryde 1998*) in the text, but alphabetic labels (like *SR98*) in the bibliography. (But unless you put in extra work the alphabetic labels will not appear anywhere except in the bibliography.)

If you want author-year citations, load `biblatex` as

```
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear,
  ]{biblatex}
```

If you want alphabetic labels, choose

```
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=alphabetic,
  ]{biblatex}
```